# Run-time crash BridgeFromObjectiveC when format date string to Foundation.Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

We've got kind of a weird bug in our app that only one user encounters so far (out of thousands) and I can't figure it out how to solve this, so maybe you can help me further.

It's about the following crash (run-time):

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftFoundation.dylib       0x10e51ec _TZFV10Foundation4Date36_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveCfGSqCSo6NSDate_S0_ + 68
1  XXX                            0x14d804 specialized static Loader._save(NSDictionary, Double, moc : NSManagedObjectContext) -> () (Loader.swift:149)
2  XXX                            0x14d804 specialized static Loader._save(NSDictionary, Double, moc : NSManagedObjectContext) -> () (Loader.swift:149)
3  XXX                            0x14286c static Loader.(registerUser(NSManagedObjectContext) -> ()).(closure #1) (Loader.swift)
4  Alamofire                      0x5aea58 specialized DataRequest.(response<A where ...> (queue : DispatchQueue?, responseSerializer : A, completionHandler : (DataResponse<A.SerializedObject>) -> ()) -> Self).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ResponseSerialization.swift)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b911797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b911783 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b915d05 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 902
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1c1ffd69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1c1fde19 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1c1510ef CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1c150f11 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
12 GraphicsServices               0x1d8fbb41 GSEventRunModal + 80
13 UIKit                          0x214d5e83 UIApplicationMain + 150
14 XXX                            0xb7b1c main (AppDelegate.swift:26)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b93e4eb start + 2
```

Line 149 of Loader.swift is:

`let createDate : Foundation.Date = dateFormatter.date(from: eventCreated)!`

It looks like it's an internal problem inside libswiftFoundation.dylib.
I've researched a lot about this problem and the only thing I could find on this was from Apple:

> Some Objective-C methods in the SDKs may incorrectly annotate or assume a type to be nonnull rather than nullable. A type that Swift treats as a struct, such as NSURL (Foundation.URL) or NSDate (Foundation.Date), results in a run-time crash in a method with a name like bridgeFromObjectiveC; in other cases, it can lead to crashes or undefined behavior in user code. If you identify such a method, please file a report at bugreport.apple.com. As a workaround, add a trampoline function in Objective-C with the correct nullability annotations. For example, the following function will allow you to call FileManager'senumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:) method with an error handler that accepts nil URLs:
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html (under known issues)

With an example that looks like this:

```
static inline NSDirectoryEnumerator<NSURL *> * _Nullable

fileManagerEnumeratorAtURL(NSFileManager *fileManager, NSURL * _Nonnull url, NSArray<NSURLResourceKey> * _Nullable keys, NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions options, BOOL (^ _Nullable errorHandler)(NSURL * _Nullable errorURL, NSError * _Nonnull error)) {
     return [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:url includingPropertiesForKeys:keys options:options errorHandler:^(NSURL * _Nonnull errorURL, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
          return errorHandler(errorURL, error);
       }];
}
```

I've already submitted a bug report for this issue, but still haven't got a response from Apple (after 7 days). I think this could fix the problem, but I'm not sure on how to port the given trampoline function (example) to a valid/working NSDate/DateFormatter version. Does someone know more about this problem and/or got it solved?

Comment: Your problem likely results from trying to force-unwrap the optional return value of `date()`.  Try changing the code as follows:  `if let createDate : Foundation.Date = dateFormatter.date(from: eventCreated) {
    // continue normal processing
} else {
    // handle the problem
}
`